# Mocking Java Class from Groovy Test case

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit, mocking

I am trying to write a test case in groovy for a class that is written in java. The Java class(name:Helper) has a method in it where a HttpClient object is obtained and executeMethod is called on it. I am trying to mock this httpClient.executeMethod() in groovy test case, but not able to mock it right.

Below is the Java class
//this helper class is a java class

```
public class Helper{

public static message(final String serviceUrl){   
----------some code--------

HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
HttpMethod httpmethod = new HttpMethod();

// the below is the line that iam trying to mock
String code = httpClient.executeMethod(method);

}
}
```

The test case that i have written in groovy so far is:

```
    void testSendMessage(){
        def serviceUrl = properties.getProperty("ITEM").toString()

    // mocking to return null   
def mockJobServiceFactory = new MockFor(HttpClient)
    mockJobServiceFactory.demand.executeMethod{ HttpMethod str ->
                return null
            }

    mockJobServiceFactory.use {         
             def responseXml = helper.message(serviceUrl)

            }   
        }
```

Any ideas on why it is not mocking correctly.
Advance Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this approach](http://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/unit-testing-with-httpclients-localtestserver/) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Well!
Is very hard to test static methods, and even harder to test local variables unless you declare them as properties. My conclusion about the static classes sometimes is about design, because you can put that block of code in other place and reuse. Anyway, here is my approach to test with nothing, with stub, with a mock and with MOP this case:

This a Java class like your class:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

public class Helper{

  public static String message(final String serviceUrl) throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    Date d = formatter.parse(serviceUrl);
    String code = d.toString();
    return code;
  }
}
```

And this is my GroovyTestCase:

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import groovy.mock.interceptor.StubFor
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

class TestHelper extends GroovyTestCase{

  void testSendMessageNoMock(){
    def h = new Helper().message("01-01-12")
    assertNotNull h
    println h
  }

  void testSendMessageWithStub(){
    def mock = new StubFor(SimpleDateFormat)
    mock.demand.parse(1..1) { String s -> 
      (new Date() + 1) 
    }
    mock.use {
      def h = new Helper().message("01-01-12")
      assertNotNull h
    }
  }

  void testSendMessageWithMock(){
    def mock = new MockFor(SimpleDateFormat)
    mock.demand.parse(1..1) { String s -> 
      (new Date() + 1) 
    }
    shouldFail(){
      mock.use {
        def h = new Helper().message("01-01-12")
        println h
      }  
    }
  }

  void testSendMessageWithMOP(){
    SimpleDateFormat.metaClass.parse = { String s -> 
      println "MOP"
      new Date() + 1 
    }
    def formatter = new SimpleDateFormat()
    println formatter.parse("hello world!")
    println " Exe: " +  new Helper().message("01-01-12")
  }
}
```

The answer to your question maybe is: because is a local variable in a method, and that is not a collaborator to test.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the compiled Java class does not go via Groovy's meta object protocol (MOP) when constructing the *HttpClient* instance so the mocked object is not instantiated.

Since *HttpClient* instances are thread safe I'd think about injecting it into the class as a dependency, that way the test can simply inject the mock instead.

Comment: could you please be a bit more specific. or do you have any example on how to achieve it

Comment: Very interested in workaround or related resources, if possible. Thx.