# Mock final class in Spock

Tags: mocking, final, spock

Can spock mock final classes?  If so, how?  Search results brought up this [gist](https://gist.github.com/craigatk/8994836#file-build-gradle), which would seem to imply so, but I can't find any examples of doing so.  I've also found forum posts that say mocking final classes isn't supported.

Comment: Sometimes, with Groovy it's best to just give it a try.

Comment: @cjstehno I tried, and got an exception.  But I figured maybe there's a special way of doing it that I don't know about.

Comment: The short answer is no, there is an open issue about that. https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/735

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This specification:

```java
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def 'lol'() {
        given: 
        def s = Mock(String) {
            size() >> 10
        }

        expect:
        s.size() == 10        
    }
}
```

ends with the following exception:

```
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 1, Time: 29 Test Failure:
lol(Test) org.spockframework.mock.CannotCreateMockException:
Cannot create mock for class java.lang.String because Java mocks cannot mock final classes.
If the code under test is written in Groovy, use Groovy mock.
```

The solution is to use `GroovyMock`:

```java
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def 'lol'() {
        given: 
        def s = GroovyMock(String) {
            size() >> 10
        }

        expect:
        s.size() == 10        
    }
}
```

Which works well.

Comment: Could the difference with String.length() be because it's defined on the Java String class, not the Groovy version?  This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12177035/369722) seems to suggest so.

Comment: @JulianA.  This is my experience too: GroovyMock seems to be no help with most Java class final methods.  I'd like some clarfication on this... !

Comment: Is there any other option other than using GroovyMock? Does Spock provide any other workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

There is a third-party library https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable that seems to do the job. Not sure why it's not so popular.

Comment: I tried it and it just completely failed to do anything.  Maybe that's why it's not popular.